# Exceptions at while(rs.next())

Tags: java, rest, web, jdbc

I have this piece of code in the backend of a web application. It sometimes throws a NullPointerException at while(rs.next()), sometimes it throws SQLException Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed also at while(rs.next()), but sometimes it doesn't throw any error. Anyone knows what is the problem?

```
public HashSet<LocalDate> getAvailableDates(long listingNumber) throws SQLException{
    Statement statement = null;
    String getDatesAvail = "SELECT AVAILDATE FROM AVAILABILITY WHERE LISTINGNUM = " +listingNumber +";";
    HashSet<LocalDate> avail = new HashSet<LocalDate>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        connect(); // Open dbConnection
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(getDatesAvail);
        System.out.println(getDatesAvail);
        if (rs == null) {
            System.out.println("Result set is null for avail");
        }
        while(rs.next()) {
            avail.add(LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("AVAILDATE"), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new SQLException();
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return avail;
}
```

My connect() method:

```
private void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is the stack trace for NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6309)
    at car_service.JDBCConnector.getAvailableDates(JDBCConnector.java:1170)
    at car_service.JDBCConnector.getListing(JDBCConnector.java:974)
    at car_service.ListingController.getListing(ListingController.java:347)
    at car_service.ListingController.lambda$6(ListingController.java:94)
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the stack trace for SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:743)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6288)
    at car_service.JDBCConnector.getAvailableDates(JDBCConnector.java:1170)
    at car_service.JDBCConnector.getListing(JDBCConnector.java:974)
    at car_service.ListingController.getListing(ListingController.java:347)
    at car_service.ListingController.lambda$6(ListingController.java:94)
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If `rs` is `null` , you should stop your logic (e.g `return` from your method) ..

Comment: @Berger From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)): a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; **never null**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Yes I also saw that, but the comment was meant to point an obvious flaw (could help later for situations where `null` may happen)

Comment: Can you please include the relevant portion of the stack trace?

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace, and consider posting a [mcve], for example given the `dbConnection` is not method local, you may very well be suffering from race conditions by incorrectly sharing a connection with multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're assuming that the OP is using a JDBC driver that conforms to the specification. While most do in this respect, we can't be 100% sure that this implementation does not return `null` here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wouldn't be surprised either way.  I would like to see the stack trace though.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? Are you sure you are not using the same JDBC connection from multiple threads? That could explain intermittent errors. You may want to consider keeping the connection local to the method, and not as a field in your class.

Comment: I have added the Exception stack trace.

Comment: @Berger If `rs` was null, `ResultSetImpl.next()` could not possibly appear in the stack trace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46. I don't use any multi-threading in my code.

Comment: Are you sure? Web applications are usually multi-threaded when handling multiple requests. In any case, consider changing your code so the connection is created and kept local to the method instead of sharing it in your class. In any case, you really need to post a [mcve]. There are too many unknowns here, and the behavior really suggests you are using the same connection in parallel.

Comment: I amwith @MarkRotteveel. I ran into similar problem almost 2 decades back when I shared one db connection object with multiple threads. Well, it was a webapp. At that time I was naive enough to not understand threading model of web server. My code threw many surprises at random. Though I did not understand the exact reason at that time, I changed db connection to method local and survived the day!

Comment: @Lyndt Of course you're using threads. This is a Web server. Have a look at the stack trace. Threads all over it.

Comment: And any JDBC driver that delivered null would last about five mnutes before being fixed. Nobody checks this for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe. You have made the mistake of storing the `Connection` object as a member variable. It should be a local variable, and opened and closed within the method, with a connection pool underlying it.